# Remove the hash from url

Tags: jquery, hash

I have the following code :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.tab-title').on('click', function(e) {
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
      e.preventDefault();
    var _self = $(this);
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    _self.parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

and my PHP

```
<div class="tab active">
    <a href="<?php the_field('service_name');?>" class="tab-title"><?php the_field('service_title'); ?></a> 
</div> 
 <div class="tab-content">  
<h2><?php the_field('service_title'); ?> </h2>
    <p><?php the_field('service_desc'); ?></p>
    <p><?php the_field('service_area');?></p>
</div>
```

The site url : `mysite.com/services/marketing/#internet`

The problem is the (#) which included in the site url. Is it possible to remove this from URL?

Comment: Do u want to remove only # or #internet?

Comment: But you're explicitly setting it in your code. Do you just not want to set it, i.e. delete the `window.location.hash` line, or something else? It does serve a purpose: it allows someone who's bookmarked or copy/pasted the URL to come back to the correct tab, assuming you have equivalent code to process that on start.

Comment: @Sree i want to remove only the (#)

Comment: @Rup, if i remove the `window.location.hash` then not load / appear the url, and i have the following structure : `mysite/services/marketing` and not `mystie/services/marketing/internet`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

**EDITED**

**Try the following code if you want to remove only `#` from the url:**

```
history.pushState({}, document.title, location.href.replace('#', "/"));
```

**The pushState() method**

pushState() takes three parameters: a state object, a title (which is currently ignored), and (optionally) a URL. Let's examine each of these three parameters in more detail:

- **state object:** The state object is a JavaScript object which is
  associated with the new history entry created by pushState().
  Whenever the user navigates to the new state, a popstate event is
  fired, and the state property of the event contains a copy of the
  history entry's state object.

  The state object can be anything that can be serialized. Because
  Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be
  restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit
  of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state
  object. If you pass a state object whose serialized representation is
  larger than this to pushState(), the method will throw an exception.
  If you need more space than this, you're encouraged to use
  sessionStorage and/or localStorage.
- **title:** Firefox currently ignores this parameter, although it may use
  it in the future. Passing the empty string here should be safe
  against future changes to the method. Alternatively, you could pass a
  short title for the state to which you're moving.
- **URL:** The new history entry's URL is given by this parameter. Note
  that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to
  pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance
  after the user restarts the browser. The new URL does not need to be
  absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current
  URL. The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL;
  otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception. This parameter is
  optional; if it isn't specified, it's set to the document's current
  URL.

Look at this for more info [History_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: I think you're right he wants the history API, but it looks like he wants the selected tab name on the end of the URL too - and in the title too I'd guess - and I've seen `null` more often than `""` for no data.

Comment: @MikeD I edited the answer. Added some details about `pushState` method. Look for more info please :)

Comment: @AhmadPayan thanks for the information. Please, can you tell me if you want any other information? I add all my code. Thanks

Comment: @MikeD I edited the answer again, Hope this will help :)

Comment: @AhmadPayan thanks for the feedback. I remember that this solution which you refereed i will tried, but i don't have the results that i really want. I add the line of code below the `window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');` , the # removed but every time that i am tabbed in different service then loads the previous and current title of service. As an example : `http://mysite/services/digital-marketing//seo/ppc/social/email-marketing`

Answer (score 0):

After many hours and with clear mind i find the solution.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.tab-title').on('click', function(e) {
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
      history.pushState({}, document.title, location.hash.replace('#', "/"));
      e.preventDefault();
    var _self = $(this);
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    _self.parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

and then i follow a manual way to add my URL for very page.